# When does AzureFileSync delete its snapshots?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

AzureFileSync agent (later called AFS) makes two initial snapshots of StorageAccount/Files.
They are tagged with `Initiator = AzureFileSync`.

1. Is AFS going to delete its snapshots? When?
2. Does AFS need its snapshots to work correctly?
3. Is it safe to delete AFS's snapshots manually?
4. Are manually made snapshots safe from being deleted by AFS?

[image: Azue share snapshots]

Answer (score 0):

Azure Files can retain a maximum of 200 share snapshots. Share snapshots do not count toward the share quota, so there is no per-share limit on the total space that's used by all the share snapshots. Storage account limits still apply. After 200 share snapshots, you must delete older snapshots to create new share snapshots.

If you have active share snapshots on your share, you cannot delete your share. You can use an API to delete share snapshots, along with the share. You also can delete both the share snapshots and the share in the Azure portal.

If you delete your storage account, the share snapshots also are deleted.
you can delete the share snapshot for the period when the churn was highest.

Azure File Sync automatically takes share snapshots and file snapshots for internal use. We also have our own logic about when to remove these snapshots. We’re interested to know what you think about this – please vote for this item and comment below if you think we need better/different controls/reporting for this.

You can delete manually create Snapshot

If what you actually want is the ability to do snapshots and have retention policies for snapshots for the purpose of Backup, please vote on this item: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/31827694-schedule-snapshots-of-azure-file-shares

Does AFS need its snapshots to work correctly? Need more info on this

Comment: "Does AFS need its snapshots to work correctly? Need more info on this" - I mean.. Will I break anything if I decide to delete snapshots marked as "AzureFileSync". You said they are done for internal use.

Comment: "We also have our own logic about when to remove these snapshots." - OK, so what is a logic for "when"?

Comment: Voted. For now I'm utilizing a Automation/Runbook for scheduled snapshots and retention.